# How to check if a certain field across list of dicts are equal?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a list of dicts that all contain some common key (`a` in the below example), how can I Pythonically check whether the value associated with such a key is the same in all of them?

Example:
Check if `a` is the same across all dicts.

```
dicts = [{'a': 1, 'b':2}, {'a': 1, 'c':2}, {'a': 1, 'd':2}, {'a': 1, 'e':2}]
last_key = None
for d in dicts:
    if last_key is None:
        last_key = d['a']
    else:
       if last_key != d['a']:
          return False
return True
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: can you give us an example?

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? Collecting the values from all dictionaries? Checking whether all items in a list are equal?

Comment: @ClaireNielsen See my example. I want it to be cleaner and more pythonic.

Comment: @Azhy  See my example. I want it to be cleaner and more pythonic.

Comment: @mkrieger1  See my example. I want it to be cleaner and more pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
len({d[key] for d in dicts}) == 1
```

or using your example:

```
def equal_key(dicts, key):
    return len({d[key] for d in dicts}) == 1

print(equal_key([{'a': 1, 'b':2}, {'a': 1, 'c':2}, {'a': 1, 'd':2}, {'a': 1, 'e':2}], 'a')  # True
```